# Redirecting to a firebase dynamic link doesn't open up IOS App

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

When I try to redirect user click on a website URL (firebase hosting) to a Firebase dynamic link (implemented in firebase cloud function that links to firebase hosted url) it doesn't open up the IOS App.

However, click on the Firebase dynamic link directly opens up the IOS App.

I wanted to check if there is a way to address this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firebase Dynamic Links are using iOS Universal Links under the hood. User Interaction is required to activate Universal Links. Server redirect or JavaScript redirect will not activate the Universal Link.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As an workaround to url redirect, I created a transition page with "Open in App" has the dynamic link url encoded and the transition page is redirected to by user click.  If there is a better solution for the workaround would love to know that.

Comment: Firebase Dynamic Links does provide such Interstitial page already. Check out parameter "efr"  - enable force redirect. If you do not specify "efr" or specify "efr=0" we will show the Interstitial page with button. This page will be shown only if Universal Links failed to engage. Tapping on "Open" button on this page will open the App if App is installed. We also added more customization option for this Interstitial page, please try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding efr=0 in your link.